# Why could integral of the both side of a differential equation be wrong

Tags: calculus

Given a differential equation,

$f'(t) = f(t) + g(t)$

Find the formula for $h(t) = \int_0^tf(x)dx$. But, how come the following solution is incorrect? What is wrong? What will happen when $g(t)$ is a function of pulses?

Because,

$\int_0^tf'(x)dx = \int_0^tf(x)dx + \int_0^tg(x)dx$

so that,

$h(t) = \int_0^tf(x)dx = f(t) - f(0) - \int_0^tg(x)dx$

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking.

Comment: You haven't computed $f$, which can be expressed in terms of $g$.

Comment: Your steps so far are not wrong, but do not lead to a solution of the differential equiaton.

Comment: For $g=0$ you have the solution $f(t)=e^t$. Maybe this helps.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any mistakes in your reasoning. But, as [logarithm](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/669389/logarithm) alluded to in a comment, perhaps you were supposed to write *h* in terms of *g* only, without mentioning *f*. If so, then you've written a correct statement, but you haven't answered the question.